# Create a list of tuples from a list of m items and an m x m array of similarities

Tags: python, list, dataframe, tuples, similarity

I have a list of 3 Items.

```
Items_list = ['a','b','c']
```

sklearn cosinesimilarities function gives me an output of 3 x 3 matrix for all the combinations of items 'a','b' and 'c' as follows:

```
similarities =[[1, 0.5, 0.2],
               [0.5, 1, 0.6],
               [0.2, 0.6, 1]]
```

I want to create a Pandas DataFrame with two columns as follows:
Required Output:

```
  Col1                          Col2
0    a  [(a, 1), (b, 0.5), (c, 0.2)]
1    b  [(a, 0.5), (b, 1), (c, 0.6)]
2    c  [(a, 0.2), (b, 0.6), (c, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope that's what you need

```
import pandas as pd

item_list = ['a','b','c']

similarities =[[1, 0.5, 0.2],
               [0.5, 1, 0.6],
               [0.2, 0.6, 1]]

tuple_similarities = [list(zip(item_list, row)) for row in similarities]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': item_list,
                   'Col2': tuple_similarities})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Col1                          Col2
0    a  [(a, 1), (b, 0.5), (c, 0.2)]
1    b  [(a, 0.5), (b, 1), (c, 0.6)]
2    c  [(a, 0.2), (b, 0.6), (c, 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks Sergei. I want a in col1 and list of all 3 tuples in col2. So the dataframe will have 3 rows - each for a, b, c and the respective similarities.

Comment: The first row second column should be an array [('a',1), ('b',0.5), ('c',0.2)].